# disable hardware button and soft key on click

Tags: java, android

I want to **disable home button** and recent button on click

i am trying this but its not working

```
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14)
            getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Comment: You cannot `disable home button` !